is this libnss-mdns misconfiguration or something else?
I have Focal system running on my laptop
When I try to execute any NSS-enabled tool which implies query to mDNS/Avahi about rabbit.local host (also Ubuntu laptop), all tools using libnss-mdns fail to resolve, but Avahi tools see that record perfectly:
ping for IPv4
$ ping rabbit.local
ping: rabbit.local: Name or service not known

ping for IPv6
$ ping6 rabbit.local
ping6: rabbit.local: Name or service not known

but avahi tools are just fine
$ avahi-resolve-host-name -v rabbit.local
Server version: avahi 0.7; Host name: otter.local
rabbit.local    192.168.1.<skipped>

$ avahi-browse -at
<skipped>
 + wlp0s20f3 IPv6 rabbit                                        SFTP File Transfer   local
<skipped>
 + wlp0s20f3 IPv4 rabbit                                        SFTP File Transfer   local
<skipped>
 + wlp0s20f3 IPv6 rabbit                                        SSH Remote Terminal  local
 + wlp0s20f3 IPv4 rabbit                                        SSH Remote Terminal  local
<skipped>

to me this looks like ping (and other NSS-enabled tools) somehow can not get mDNS info from Avahi, but Avahi itself is just fine. how to dig it through quick?
none of these 3 actions helped:

closing and opening laptop cover, to go sleep and wake up, in order to shake wifi
manual off and on for wifi
executing ''sudo service networking restart''

just in case, nss config is:
$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mymachines
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis



Is libnss-mdns installed? What is output of apt-cache policy libnss-mdns?

@mpboden

$ apt-cache policy libnss-mdns
libnss-mdns:
  Installed: 0.14.1-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.14.1-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.14.1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


